# Zip multiple folders and files depending on filesize in Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, zip, filesize

I have a directory "mapnik" with hundreds of sub-directories, each containing more than 10000 files. I would like to zip "mapnik" recursively, preserving the folder-structure but only adding files greater than 103 Byte to the archive.

How can I accomplish this? I tried using find and pipes, but with the wrong syntax and the huge number of files, "trial and error" is not the best way to get it done ;)

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delan's suggestion produced some kind of zip-error whith files of the same name. But it got me on the right track. This is what worked for me:

```
cd mapnik
find . -size +103c -print | zip archive.zip -@
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
find -size +103c -print0 | xargs -0 zip -r outname.zip
```